# Is mattn/go-sqlite3's regexp extension faster than sqlite3's LIKE operator for '%word%' searches?

Tags: sqlite, go

I am currently using mattn's go-sqlite3 package and am looking to do many select statement searches with LIKE '%word%' conditions. Is mattn's regexp extension faster than the sqlite's built in LIKE operator? (more specifically for LIKE '%word%' searches)

Comment: Have you tried writing some benchmarks? http://golang.org/pkg/testing/

Answer (score 0):

The [`mattn/go-sqlite3`](https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3) project itself has already quite a few example of [`SELECT` benchmarks](https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/blob/25d045f12a64283630fdedec899655cc5710b683/sqlite3_test/sqltest.go#L360-L382)

```
func BenchmarkRows(b *testing.B) {
    db.once.Do(makeBench)
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
    var n sql.NullString
    var i int
    var f float64
    var s string
    var t time.Time
    r, err := db.Query("select * from bench")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    ...
}
```

You can adapt them for your specific tests.